# Firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm still new with Firebase cloud messaging.

Whenever I send a push notification to an app, does it get recorded in this table in the firebase console like in the image below?

[image: Cloud messaging notification in Firebase console under category grow]

Answer (score 1):

That only shows notifications that you compose at the console.  It doesn't show messages that you send programmatically with the Admin SDK or HTTP API.

Comment: I see. So there is no way for me to get the list of notification I sent? May I also ask if there is a code where it can compose a message like the console?

Comment: You can record a list of notifications yourself in a database such as Firestore or Realtime Database.  There is currently no programmatic message composer that does the exact same thing as the console.

Comment: But is there a possibility that the programmatic message composer would be added in the future?

Comment: I don't know, but you can always file a feature request.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features